# Term (phrase or word) for action to take as a penalty for losing a bet (or a game, etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In particular, an embarrassing or undesirable action.

For example:

- If I lose this bet, I will shave my head. What will your _____ be?
- What _____ should we set for losing this game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **forfeit**, that is given up or performed by the player losing the game or committing a fault.

In your first example, the second sentence would be "What forfeit will you pay ?".

[Example](http://www.independent.ie/sport/leftfield/jamie-carragher-breaks-and-agrees-to-wear-manchester-united-shirt-as-bet-forfeit-31344031.html): *Jamie Carragher (Liverpool FC) has agreed to suffer the forfeit of wearing a Manchester United shirt after losing a bet with Gary Neville that relates to Tottenham midfielder Paulinho*.

Comment: Wouldn't *"What will you forfeit?"* work better than *"What forfeit will you pay?"*.

Comment: *Forfeit* as a noun in this sense is rather old-fashioned (at least in North America), although its use as a verb is fairly standard.

Comment: It's not old-fashioned in British English.

Comment: This is the closest term I have seen which fits the meaning and feel of what I was referring to. With "penance" being a close second

Answer (score 1):

It's a *stake*, of the not vampire-stabbing sort.

> *stake NOUN* A sum of money or something else of value gambled on the outcome of a risky game or venture - [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake#nav2)
>
> *figurative* the opposition raised the stakes in the battle for power

Answer (score 1):

This isn't technically right, but you may want to use it anyway:

*penance*

Literally, this is defined:

*something that you do or are given to do in order to show that you are sad or sorry about doing something wrong*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penance

So it is only an approximate fit -- but it sort of works in an imprecise way.

Comment: I like this one. It reminds me of the Spanish word penitencia which is a better fit in this context. I guess I was looking for an equivalent term in English

Comment: @DanielV - Yes, sometimes a word works because of the *feel*, not the definition or even the connotation.

Answer (score -1):

Punishment 
Consequence

The word "set" in the second sentence does not seem to work or even necessary depending on what precedes it.

Establish 
Determine 
Agree upon 
Enforce

Stakes (although the sentence may need further revision)

Comment: Please read the comments under [another answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/348468/18696) and consider revising yours to include data explaining why your suggestions are suitable.

Comment: I suppose that as a high school teacher I am used to composing answers with explanations like the one I provided that was determined objectionable.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for the word **wager**.

Comment: I thought of that too but I wasn't sure if there was a better fit for denoting an embarrassing or humiliating action

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Why is *wager* the word being looked for?

Comment: Read the question, and then read the answer. Let's keep it as succinct as possible.

Comment: Hi, codeforce1. I think Matt E. Эллен was trying to encourage you to make your posted response more useful to future readers of this Q&A by transforming it into a complete, self-contained answer. As matters stand, every reader who wants to make sense of your answer must look up _wager_ in a dictionary and try to find a meaning that makes sense in the context of the poster's question. You could save a lot of people time by doing that research and citing that definition yourself in your answer. Doing so might also attract more upvotes for your answer, if that is a matter of interest to you.